# Travel ban to South Africa. What can I do?

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, south-africa, visa-bans

I was born and raised in South Africa and have been declared undesirable for 5 years. I didn't realise I could be banned! I didn't have a clue. I showed them my birth certificate and was told it's not a full birth certificate, so I pointed out the writing where it says full birth certificate. I was horrified to be banned as I still have my fiance and family in South Africa.

I entered South Africa on a British passport which was obtained for me by my mother when I was 16 I didn't have a choice of leaving as I was underage. I have a British passport. I'm currently in Ireland staying with family but it's only temporary. I've currently got 2 lawyers and still no response from the home office. I haven't had any response from phone calls, emails to DHA or overstay appeals. I am beyond desperate. As I said I made the big mistake of travelling in and out of South Africa on a British passport and obviously overstayed by a few months.

I have now been waiting for almost a year for some kind of response from anyone. I did make sure to send my appeal within the recommended 10 days. I have spent thousands on lawyer's fees still with no response. What can I do?

Comment: When did you last enter SA and on what basis? When did you leave? Is it possible you [lost your SA citizenship](https://legalfundi.com/legal-question/how-can-a-person-lose-south-african-citizenship/)? What is your citizenship (as it seems it’s not SA) and where are you living now? No response *at all* from your lawyers?

Comment: Sorry, if your lawyers weren't able to help you, your chances of finding something better here are close to zero especially if you provide no relevant details. Losing your citizenship (if you ever had it) is fairly serious and that requires professional help.

Comment: Hi there. To answer your questions... I entered South Africa on a British passport which was obtained for me by my mother when I was 16 I didn't have a choice of leaving as I was underage. I have a British passport. I'm currently in Ireland staying with family but it's only temporary. I've currently got 2 lawyers and still no response from the home office. I haven't had any response from phone calls, emails to DHA or overstay appeals. I am beyond desperate. As I said I made the big mistake of travelling in and out of South Africa on a British passport and obviously overstayed by a few months.

Comment: I just need someone who can help me. I'm so desperate to get help and to get a resolve from the home office but it seems like I'll have to pay thousands more to take them to court as far as my lawyer is concerned. I'm already in debt paying for the first lawyer who's done nothing to be honest. They said they gave the home office 7 days to respond it's been a month now and still nothing from the lawyer or the home office. The one lawyer said I should keep emailing and phoning the home office and see what happens which I'm doing but what am I paying them to do?

Comment: I'm currently looking at going to citizens advice in Ireland to declare myself homeless. I will probably have to break up with my fiance as I don't know how much longer this is going to take and the strain is immense on our relationship. He can't come here for family reasons and I can't go there. My dad is 74 I wanted him to walk me down the aisle but if he lasts another 4or 5 years I'd be surprised but I probably won't be getting married by then anyway so that's null and void. My lawyer said I'd get a response in a month or so it's now been 6. So what am I supposed to do!

Comment: @Lp123 please stop posting nonsense. Have you contacted a RSA embassy in the UK? Ask if your citizenship is still valid and if yes, request a RSA passport. If your citizenship is lost, you'll have to wait until your travel ban is over.

Comment: What is the citizenship of your parents? If they were not SA nationals, were they permanent residents in SA when you were born? What is your travel history in and our of SA? You may very well never have been an SA citizen, and if you overstayed, then there is probably no valid reason for an appeal.

Comment: Ask a lawyer if you are more likely to be admissible if you married your fiance, assuming he/she is a SA citizen.  Most countries look more favorably on admitting spouses of citizens than tourist visitors.

Comment: @Lp123 While I have some sympathy with your situation, the immediate answer to *’what can I do’* is **stop throwing money at lawyers**. South Africans don’t need a visa to visit ROI and there are direct flights between the two countries, making short-ish visits feasible. Follow the advice in gerrit’s answer to contact the SA embassy in ROI, resolve your citizenship status once and for all and then sort the rest out based on facts and what is possible, rather than on drama and desperation.

Answer (score 11):

Contact the embassy of South Africa in the country in which you are located.  Ask them if you have South African citizenship.  If you do, apply for a passport.  If you don't, wait until your travel ban is over.

Perhaps your fiance and you can both travel to a third country with a liberal visa/immigration policy.

Comment: Actually, it is quite possible OP never had South African citizenship, if both parents are UK citizens they would not have received SA citizenship at birth, but only at majority if they had stayed in SA since birth with the correct status (which was apparently not the case if I understand the comments correctly).

Comment: @jcaron True.  Removed the word "still".